# How to invoke a script in the currently running QGIS instance from the command line?

Tags: qgis

From the Windows Command Prompt (or Batchfile) I want to find the running QGIS instance  with an open project. Afterwards a script (eg. zoom to something) should be automatically started. 
I've tried it with `qgis.bat --code`

That works fine, but always starts a new QGIS instance. - I don't want that!

In future I want to register a Windows Protocol for something like `link2qgis:layer="layer".featid="123".action=zoomto`

When clicking on that url in some third party application, the QGIS instance should be maximized and the map canvas should be zoomed to the feat.

Maybe someone has already done something similar and can help me with that.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? If so it would be great if you could post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I see you can do this (there might be more)

1. a web server running in the QGIS instance that listens for requests
2. sockets

For 1. you can use something like Flask or the built in Python HTTP server running in a thread that just listens for for stuff and acts on it. You could use something like Curl (which might be installed with QGIS to call it from the command line)