# How to trigger qgis command from outside of qgis

Tags: qgis, python

Imagine you have a simple (maybe shared) EXCEL sheet lising your coordinates. For each coordinate you want to check a feature in a layer or arial imagery. To make it efficient, it would be perfect to "click" and jump to that position in QGis (a running qgis with layers and styles loaded).

A VBA code or com-addin in that example could run a command to do that.

I need to achieve the following:
call QGIS from another application and say "zoomWithCenter" and "zoomScale"

Is this possible? How?

I am running a QGIS on a windows machine.

I would like to view some layers with QGIS but the editing and tracking is done in another custom application.

It would be great to e.g. send a command line call (holding coordinates and zoom scale) from that other application to running QGIS in order to pan and zoom to a particular coordinate.

Maybe there is already a socket server and client available for qgis? That would even allow two way communication...

Comment: Do you mean to programmatically launch QGIS?

Comment: I mean: when QGis is launched and layers are loaded, how can I center and zoom from parameters provided by another application.

Comment: can you edit your question to include that extra detail.   What other application did you have in mind for example?

Comment: What application are you wanting to launch QGIS from, and how to do you plan to do it with this application?  Is this from code or just running the executable?

Comment: I want to interface with a running qgis. I want to send simple commands like zoom and pan to it. As this can be done with python code, maybe there is an easy way to run a python script from another application?

Comment: Related, but also without an answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130053/how-to-invoke-a-script-in-the-currently-running-qgis-instance-from-the-command-l

Comment: I had sockets in mind. Is it possible to run an async python script to provide socket client and server? That would solve the problem I guess.

Comment: another related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/how-to-run-a-simple-python-script-for-qgis-from-outside-e-g-sublime-text?rq=1. But this does not cover the need to interact with an already running qgis